# AWS athena - Get unique device row data for latest timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

i have a table in aws athena as shown below.
[image]

and i want to get rows for each device id with highest timestamp.

Comment: AWS Athena does not use MySQL. Please dont tag other irrelevant RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

With ansi-sql you just need a sub-select with a group by and aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT distinct last_record.*
FROM changesets AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        c2.user,
        MAX(c2.created_at) AS max_timestamp
    FROM changesets AS c2
    GROUP BY  c2.user
) AS last_record
    ON c.user = last_record.user
```

And of course don't forget if deviceId is not the primary-key or non-unique this will return multiple rows from **last_record** so you will need the **distinct**